# How to inject properties file to a Class?

Tags: java, spring

I'm learning Spring. And I trying to inject file Properties to a Class (not a Bean).

So my Idea is: I inject attributes from properties file to a Class (Name is MyConfig.java). And I will condition fields in MyConfig then run a @Bean to config.

What should I do ? Thank all !

Answer (score 0):

See the PropertySource annotation at http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html

You can find an example from http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertysources-example/

Comment: Thank you, but how to call that Class ( after we inject ) to check conditionals ? How to check a field in that Class ?

Comment: This is my code : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37836185/autoconfig-spring-by-conditional-a-class